# Probability of biased coin

Tags: probability

For a biased coin the probability of different faces are:$$\begin{matrix}{\rm Face}&1&2&3&4&5&6\\p&0.10&0.32&0.21&0.15&0.05&0.17\end{matrix}$$
I am asked to find probability that it is face one and you are told that either face one or two has shown up.

I tried to use conditional probability condition:
$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}.$$
Here I define $A$ to be the event of getting $1$ and $B$ to be that of getting $1$ or $2$. What I am having difficulty is in evaluating $P(A ∩ B)$. Any hint?

Comment: "Getting 1 and getting 1 or 2" = Getting 1, no? (Unrelated: a "coin" with 6 faces is usually called a die rather than a coin...)

Comment: Since $A\subset B$, $A\cap B=A$

Comment: @farruhota Relevant formula? One is considering only two events here.

Comment: @farruhota Thus, no C and a very specific B...In such a context, not sure your first comment helps. Compare with kludg's comment, which is to the point.

Comment: @farruhota Which must be the longest and most offtopic way to prove this identity...

Comment: @farruhota Not sure you understand the remarks made about your first comment, anyway the kind of ridiculous "you too" counterattack you just performed is not the way mathematical debates are normally conducted. Please behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of event $B$ is either getting $1$ or $2$. Since it's an "or", we sum up the probability

$$P(B)=P(1)+P(2)=0.10 + 0.32 =0.42$$

Now the intersection between events $A$ (getting a $1$) and $B$(getting a $1$ or $2$) is the event of getting a $1$. The probability of this is $P(A\cap B) = P(1)=0.1$

So the probability is

$$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{0.1}{0.42}=\frac{5}{21}$$

***EDIT*** -While calculating $P(B)$, we use the union of $E_1$(getting a $1$) and $E_2$(getting a $2$). The reason we can directly sum them up is because they are mutually exclusive, i.e. $E_1 \cap E_2 =\phi$. This is because you can either get a $1$ or you can get a $2$, but you cannot get both.

Comment: It is an "or" yes, but the conclusion that summing up should do needs a second (satisfied) condition: the events are mutually exclusive.

Comment: True. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll edit to add it